# JavaScript - Run code when user confirms leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the user to confirm that he wants to leave the page. I do that this way with jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
    return "Are you sure?";
});
```

If the user says "yes", I want to run a function that makes an ajax request to save some data, before the browser tab closes. Is this possible? And how, in that case?

Comment: What kind of function? `onunload` exists, but will probably not work as you expect.

Comment: @minitech I need to make an AJAX request and save some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.  `beforeunload` does not allow you to do your own prompting and then branch based on how the question is answered.  It only lets you run code or return a prompt string that simply determines whether the user navigates away from the page or not.

In your particular case, I would suggest that you always save the data when you get this callback (like an autosave in a word processor).  If the user elects to stay on the page and make more changes, you can then save the  new state of the data again at a later time when they leave the page.  You will have to carefully test several browsers to make sure that an ajax call that is started in a `beforeunload` handler will properly complete.  It seems like it should, but there could be implementation differences between browsers.

---

FYI, the reason `beforeunload` is so strict is because it has to prevent abuse by malicious web pages that prevent you from leaving their web site when you want to.

Answer (score 1):

As jfriend00 mentioned what you are trying to do it not possible. You're best bet though is to be pessimistic when they press the back button. By this I mean:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        //Do ajax call to save
    });
    return "Are you sure?";
});
```

What this will do is *hopefully* give time for your ajax call to be sent and notify the server of the new data. I say hopefully because the browser will kill all requests when you navigate away from the page.

Another thing to keep in mind this will not be triggered when a user forcibly closes the browser.