# Do something after leave page with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, frontend

I need to do some back-end process when user leaves my page. My JS code works fine:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", OnBeforeUnLoad, false);
}
else {
    if (window.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
        window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", OnBeforeUnLoad);
    }
}

function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
    return "Are you sure?";
}
```

But my `OnBeforeUnLoad` function must contain an `$.ajax` call to do something on server side when user press OK on dialog prompted by browser automatically. Doing it like this doesn't work:

```
function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
   if (confirm("Are you sure?")){
      $.ajax({
         type:       "POST",
         url:        "../wp-content/scripts/removedemo.php",
         data:       "s="+UserSession.encodedurl,
         success: function(data){}
      });
   }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060534/javascript-run-code-when-user-confirms-leaving-page?rq=1

Comment: Am I unable to do anything when user confirm that he/she wants to leave? So that kind of dialogs are purely informatives, isn't it? I need to remove a folder+files previously created :\

Answer (score 0):

Use `setimeout` function to delay the execution for fraction of secs.Here is your code:

```
setTimeout(OnBeforeUnLoad, 10); 

function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
if (confirm("Are you sure?")){
  $.ajax({
     type:       "POST",
     url:        "../wp-content/scripts/removedemo.php",
     data:       "s="+UserSession.encodedurl,
     success: function(data){}
  });
}
}
```

Comment: What will I achieve with this? That code without `$.ajax` function doesn't fire any prompt when I leave the page.

Comment: Your question was that you want to connect to server side through ajax before page reload.It works.But the only problem is after certain delay it will display `confirm` box again.Need to tackle with that.